# Log4J 2 properties configuration not working

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am new to Log4J 2 and have observed several significant changes from the initial Log4j 1.X. For a test drive, I have a class emitting log statements. And the following log4j2.properties file.

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = target/rolling/rollingtest.log
appenders = console, file, rolling

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n


appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = FILE
appender.file.fileName=C:\\logs\\logs.log
appender.file.layout=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.conversionPattern=%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = target/rolling2/test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5
loggers = rolling

logger.rolling.name = org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRefs = rolling
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

I'm using log4j 2.5 and the official document says this version supports properties configuration.

> As of version 2.4, Log4j now supports configuration via properties
>   files.
>   https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#Properties

As the new version documentation mentions there are significant changes in properties file syntax, without much proper documentation or pointers, I'm stuck.

My log messages are getting send to the console but not to the file and rolling file.

What am I doing wrong? Kindly also suggest the best approach to fix it.

Thanks
Simanta